# Can I disable a cookie from being sent automatically with server requests?

Tags: security, cookies, session-cookies

I'm fairly new to website development. I'm working on a site where the user logs in with username/password, and gets a sessionID from the server in response. This sessionID is sent back to the server (and a new one returned) with each request.

I'd like the site to work properly if the user opens it in multiple tabs or windows. i.e. once logged in at one tab, opening a members-only URL in another tab works without loggin in. (And, logging out in one tab logs out from all.) I see no way of doing this without storing the latest sessionID in a cookie. That way the latest sessionID can be "shared" among all tabs.

However I am starting to read up on cookies, and some of the [security threats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). I was unaware that cookies were sent with every request. I don't need to send my cookie to the server, ever. The sessionID is added to the xhr request's headers -- not read as a cookie. So I'm wondering if there is a way to disable sending of this cookie. My only purpose for it is to allow multiple tabs/windows in the same browser to share the same session.

I was reading up on the [path parameter for cookies](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-totally-secure-cookies). Apparently this can be used to restrict when the cookie is sent to a server? What if I set the path to something that would never be used? Would this prevent the cookie from ever being sent out automatically? I only want to access it from JavaScript.

A coworker has put a lot of safeguards into the server-side of this application, which I won't go into here. So this question is just about what client-side precautions I can and should take, particularly with cookies, for optimal security. If there is a better way to allow a members-only site to work properly with multiple tabs open at once, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I discovered just now that in HTML 5 there is [local storage](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/), which stores key/value pairs much like a cookie, but is not sent with every server request. Since it's supported in every browser except IE 7 and earlier, I'll be switching to this to enable sharing data between tabs when available, and use cookies instead on IE 7 and earlier.

Comment: localStorage is indeed a good solution, but its important to notice that localStorage is not shared between http and https, while cookies do. so if you have mixed pages that won't work.

Comment: Also localStorage is not available in Private browsing mode on Safari. You have to fall back to cookies.

Comment: @AlexanderBurakevych localstorage works fine in private browsing mode, but of course storage is cleared when the session ends, as opposed to being persisted.

Answer (score 1):

The sessionID is stored in a cookie already there's no need to manage it.  Because the HTTP protocol is stateless the only way to maintain state is through a cookie.  What happens when you set a session value the server will look up the dictionary of items associated with that cookie id (session Id).

What is meant by stateless is that between requests HTTP does not know if your still alive or have closed your browser.  Therefore with each request the browser will attach all cookie values to the request on the domain.  SessionId is stored in the cookie automatically when they go to your site.  The Server then uses that value to look up anything you've set in the users session.

Depending on which programming language and/or server you're using the session could be handled differently but that's usually abstracted away from the programmer.

Now with respect to sessions, there are a number of different things that make them insecure.  For example if an attacker were able to get their hands on your session cookie value they could replay that cookie and take over your session.  So sessions aren't a terribly secure way of storing user information.  Instead what most people do is create an encrypted cookie value with the users details, the cookie could be a "session cookie" meaning as soon as the user closes their browser window the cookie is thrown away from the browser.  The encrypted cookie contains user information and role information as well as some identifier (usually the clients ip address) to verify that the user who is submitting the request is the same user the cookie was issued to.  In most programming languages there are tools that help in abstracting that away as well (such as the ASP.NET membership provider model).

Check out some details on the HTTP protocol and HTTP cookies on Wikipedia first

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

and check out the membership provider model on ASP.NET, it's a really good tool for helping to secure your site.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx3h274z(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the information, but the specific question I'm trying to ask is "What is the standard way to allow a user to access a site using multiple tabs or windows, but without having to log in again for each new tab/window he opens?" I use a cookie for this. Is that the normal way?

Comment: @VernJensen Yes as stated typically that is to use some sort of encrypted cookie with the users member information in there.  If you're using something like ASP.NET you can use the membership provider model which does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Preventing the browser sending cookies seems to defeat the object of using cookies in the first place.

If you don't want the sessionID to be sent with each request, why set the cookie? A better solution would be to use a custom response header that you send from the server to the browser - this will then be under your control and will not be sent automatically with all browser requests. You are using request headers to send your sessionID anyway so you could receive them from the server using a custom header and read this into your JavaScript from each XHR.

Comment: The point of using a cookie is to allow the members-only area of the website to be shared across multiple tabs or windows in the same browser. (So you don't have to log in again each time you open a new tab.) What is the proper way to do this, if not using a cookie? That's the question I'm trying to ask.

Comment: > "I don't need to send my cookie to the server, ever." Not quite true then, as you'll need this for the multiple tab support. Anyway, your local storage option you mentioned might be the way to go. Good luck!